# Detecting file name with Unicode characters in windows

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, unicode

Python version: 2.7.3

Filename: test snowman character --☃--.mp3

Ran the following tests, None of them proved successful.

```
>>> os.path.exist('test snowman character --☃--.mp3')
False
>>> os.path.exist(repr('test snowman character --☃--.mp3'))
False
>>> os.path.isfile('test snowman character --\\xe2\\x98\\x83--.mp3')
False
>>> os.path.isfile(r'test snowman character --\\xe2\\x98\\x83--.mp3')
False
>>> os.path.isfile('test snowman character --☃--.mp3'.decode('utf-8'))
False
```

Tried to retrieve files with glob, even that test failed.

**Objective is to detect and copy this file to another folder**,
Please Advise.

Comment: What does `os.listdir(u'.')` tell you is in the current directory?

Comment: Note: escaping the UTF8 byte sequence won't work here; but neither will using UTF8 as the Windows NTFS filesystem uses UTF16. Give python *unicode* path values here; your last version would work only if the unicode snowman is really entered into the terminal as UTF8 only.

Answer (score 3):

Use a unicode value; preferably with a unicode escape sequence:

```
os.path.isfile(u'test snowman character --\u2603--.mp3')
```

Python on Windows will use the correct Windows API for listing UTF16 files when you give it a unicode path.

For more information on how Python alters behaviour with unicode vs. bytestring file paths, see the [Python Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html#unicode-filenames).

Answer (score 1):

The Windows NTFS filesystem uses UTF-16 (just ask [Martijn Pieters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19648014/detecting-file-name-with-unicode-characters-in-windows#comment29174536_19648014)), so try this:

```
>>> os.path.exists(u'test snowman character --☃--.mp3'.encode("UTF-16"))
```

But first make sure the input encoding of the interpreter is correct. `print repr(u'test snowman character --☃--.mp3')` should output:

```
u'test snowman character --\u2603--.mp3'
```

---

**Note:** I am unable to test this as Windows CMD won't let me input snowman symbols. In any case, it turns out Python will do the right thing if you just give it a Unicode string, so the encode call is superfluous. To summarize, I recommend [Martijn Pieters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19648207/388916)' answer.

Comment: The output would be using a **single** backslash before the `u`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I copied that directly from the interpreter. Since the output representation is a "string within a string", the backslash needs to be escaped.

Comment: Right; you used *just* `repr()` in the interpreter. The interpreter uses `repr()` on that **again**. You'd normally leave off an explicit `repr()` in the interpreter, or use `print repr()`; the point is to get a round-trippable representation, something that looks like a unicode literal that can be reused again. The extra backslash here makes it that the value is not reusable, there is enough confusion here between the question and another answer about when to escape escapes.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Fair enough. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

Literal Unicode strings are supposed to start with `u'`, try `os.path.exist(u'test snowman character --☃--.mp3')`

If you want to use escape sequences it's `ur'`, as in `os.path.isfile(ur'test snowman character --\\xe2\\x98\\x83--.mp3')`

http://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/lexical_analysis.html#strings

Comment: The `.decode('utf8')` presumably takes care of that case already.

Comment: A raw unicode string retains the backslashes. The UTF8 'bytes' are taken literally, not as a codepoint. Use `\u2603` in a unicode string instead.

Comment: .decode() depends on whether the default encoding of the source document is correct. It is normally ASCII, however your string is NOT ASCII (At least not valid ASCII). see: https://wiki.python.org/moin/DefaultEncoding and http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html